# JMeter - How to change the JSON value while executing script in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, request

I am recording a Receipt-Accept scenario(Unique Number) in JMeter. Once the recording was done Jmeter fetching some values from DB like the below:

POST data:

```
{
    "pItemID": 8793120,
    "pShipHeaderID": 41343933,
    "pHeaderID": 37123507,
    "pLineID": 45338365,
    "pRCVTransID": 113927590,
    "pOrgCode": "E90",
    "pRelnum": null
}
```

this will be unique for each receipt. I don't know which value will come for the next receipt. How can I handle this?

POST data:

```
{
    "pItemID": 8793120,
    "pShipHeaderID": 41343933,
    "pHeaderID": 37123507,
    "pLineID": 45338365,
    "pRCVTransID": 113927590,
    "pOrgCode": "E90",
    "pRelnum": null
}
```

[no cookies]

I expect the values present under "POST data" should dynamically change in the run time.

Comment: Do you want to sent an unique number with each post request? Or is it that you want to verify the response of the request?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the random function to generate a random value and use the same

```
{
    "pItemID": ${__Random(0,7)},
}
```

Please check the link bellow for more information on Jmeter functions and variables
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random